# Antijoining in Multi-Index Python

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to call ids that satisfy a specific condition in a multi-indexed arrray,

`id     day         sum`
`x1     Sunday      37`
`x2     Friday      183`
 ----------`Thursday    61`
 ----------`Wednesday   28`
`x3     Friday      32`

required output:
`id     day        sum`
`x2     Friday      183`
 ----------`Thursday    61`
 ----------`Wednesday   28`
`x3     Friday      32`

If I apply `pd.xs('Sunday', level='call_day')`, all I can return are the values that are precisely Sunday.
 I would like to return all values that have Sunday or any other additional values like - Friday and Wednesday in which case the output would be,
`id     day         sum`
`x2     Friday      183`
 ----------`Thursday    61`
 ----------`Wednesday   28`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for all values of first level `id` and then select by `loc`:

```
i = df[df.index.get_level_values('day') == 'Friday'].index.get_level_values('id').tolist()
print (i)
['x2', 'x3']
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
i = df1.loc[df1['day'] == 'Friday', 'id']
```

---

```
df = df.loc[i]
print (df)
              sum
id day           
x2 Friday     183
   Thursday    61
   Wednesday   28
x3 Friday      32
```